# urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, openssl, urllib2

Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in do_open, line 1198

- Mac OS X,
- Django Version: 1.8.19,
- Python Version: 2.7.13,
- Request Method: GET,
- OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

Hi, does anybody resolve the problem?
`pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1` and `pip install requests[security]` didn't help me, if you need some more information i will wright it.

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/kernel/views.py" in dispatch
  34.         return super(AjaxViewMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  268.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  206.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
File "/Users/ernekyan/project/shop/views.py" in get_context_data
  283.                 self.object.full_price))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in urlopen
  154.     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in open
  429.         response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _open
  447.                                   '_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _call_chain
  407.             result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in https_open
  1241.                 context=self._context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in do_open
  1198.             raise URLError(err)

Exception Type: URLError at /cart/checkout/payment
Exception Value: <urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>
```

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CartPaymentInfo, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    vOutPrice = self.object.full_price
    import urllib2
    import xml.etree.ElementTree
    response = urllib2.urlopen(
        'https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/WebService/Service.asmx/CalcOutSumm?MerchantLogin=project&IncCurrLabel=QCardR&IncSum={}'.format(
            self.object.full_price))
    result = response.read()
    root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(result)
    for child in root:
        if child.tag.endswith('OutSum'):
            vOutPrice = float(child.text)
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thx @CristiFati , but this is no helpful in current subject

Comment: any solution yet?